# How do I fix bi-directional dependencies between ItemManager and ItemValidator classes?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I have a bi-directional relationship between two class, ItemManager and ItemValidator, where an ItemManager has a list of ItemValidators but each ItemValidator also takes an instance of the ItemManager it belongs to so that it can use methods from the ItemManager.

Is this bad practice? If so, what would be a better way to do it?

```
class ItemValidator:
    def __init__(self, order_manager):
        self.order_manager = order_manager

    def run(self, new_item):
        raise NotImplementedError()


class ItemValidatorImpl(ItemValidator):

    def run(self, new_item):
        existing_items = self.order_manager.list_items()  # Here is the issue as the validator needs methods from the OrderManager
        # ... validate the new item ...


class ItemManager:
    validator_classes = [ItemValidatorImpl]

    def run_validations(self, new_item):
        for validator_class in self.validator_classes:
            validator = validator_class(self)
            validator.run(new_item)

    def list_items(self):  # Method used by some validator implementations
        pass
```

Comment: I would go for a Mediator (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern), IF you really need to have that kind of bidirectional association between the classes. But first I would analyse if there is a need for the bidirectional association. 
Does the ItemValidator need a reference to ItemManager? Can you pass to the validator just the result of list_items method?

Comment: Different ItemValidators will need different methods ItemManager which is why I pass a reference to the object and not just the results of a specific method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having bi-directional relationship is OK. It's not OKif it hurts you in some way.

You have to think if you are not violating the Single Reponsibility Principle in some way by having the `Validators` be in the `Manager` because they do need to call some methods from the `Mananger` do to their work. This means that some methods that you will call on the `Manager` will require validation and others are just used to query some data for the validation. What if the `Validator` calls a method on the `Manager` that requires validation and you get an infinite recursion?

Breaking the `Manager` into smaller objects may be a better thing to do. You can still have the `Manager` and the `Validators` depend on the new objects, but you do remove the dependency to the `Manager` from the `Validators`.

You can divide methods in two categories: Commands and Queries. Command do mutations and Queries don't. Validaton should not mutate any state, so you probably will need to do only queries.

You can add another object that is designed to do only queries and pass it to the validators.

If you are building a tree structure you probably will have a parent node containing a collection of children and a child node having a reference to it's parent. In this case it's fine to have it.

Sometimes it's difficult to redesign you solution when you think of having one `Manager` class doing all the work and breaking it into smaller object can be difficult. `Manager` is a broad term and we do overuse them. We just stick everything that is related to something (like Order) into one object and this can get us into trouble.